# Pass changed files path to another command

Tags: git, bash

I have a versioning command and we have to manually run it with all the changed files.

Is it possible to pass the changed and added files to another command as argument?

I have tried solutions mentioned in this link: [is it possible to `git status` only modified files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018533/is-it-possible-to-git-status-only-modified-files), but its not working.

For sample I have made a dummy command:

```
function notify(){
    echo "*****************************************************************"
    echo $1
    echo "*****************************************************************"
}
```

And I try to use it as:

> git status -s | notify
>
> git ls-files -m | notify

[image]

Is there a way to send individual file path to such command?

---

**Edit 1:**

As rightly pointed by [mallaudin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2622118/mallaudin), I was missing `xargs`. But adding that now throws another error.

> xargs: notify: No such file or directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **xargs**

```
git ls-files -m | xargs notify
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611539/xargs-just-working-with-built-in-functions) question

`xargs` takes an executable as an argument (including custom scripts) rather than a function defined in the environment.

Either move your code to a script or use xargs to pass arguments to an external command.

You can move your function's code to a *separate* bash file e.g. `notify.bash` and use it like

```
git ls-files -m | xargs notify.bash
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. It throws following error: `xargs: notify: No such file or directory`. Still you are correct

Answer (score 0):

[Pipe output to bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454343/pipe-output-to-bash-function) this can help you.

```
function notify(){
    echo "*****************************************************************"
    read foo
    echo "*****************************************************************"
}
```